# Unordered string array comparison with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to compare two unordered arrays of strings with lodash. I have tried using the `isMatch` function but it doesn't seem do what I want. Here's what I have tried:

```
var arr1 = ['foo', 'bar']
var arr2 = ['bar', 'foo']
_.isEqual(arr1,arr2) //should return true, but instead it returns false
```

Thanks.

Comment: sort the arrays before checking for equality

Comment: Can you explain that with code please.

Comment: `_.chain([arr1, arr2]).map(sortBy).reduce(_.isEqual).value()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `sort()` the arrays to maintain the sequence for comparing it with `_.isEqual()`

```js
var arr1 = ['foo', 'bar']
var arr2 = ['bar', 'foo']
console.log(_.isEqual(arr1.sort(),arr2.sort()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```